# jquery toggle/show&hide divs

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I have this html structure:

```
<div id="home">

    <div class="section_header">
        <h1 class="left" data-target="newest"><?=lang('home_newest');?></h1>
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="newest">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="section_header">
        <h1 class="left" data-target="best"><?=lang('home_newest');?></h1>
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="best">
        ...
    </div>

</div>
```

What I am trying to do is a toggle/show&hide function to work on click **.section_header > h1** to show the div with the id defined in data-target inside h1 tag and hide the others, but always having one open and the #newest open by default on page load.

I have tried:

```
$('.section_header h1').click(function(){
    var selected = $(this).data('target');
    //$('#'+selected).hide().filter('#'+selected).show();
    $('#home > #'+selected).hide();
}).first().click();
```

The commented line doesn't work, but the .hide only it does.

I found this: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/02/more-showing-more-hiding and thought it could work but I didn't succeed to tell it which div to close and show

**Edit:**
There is one more thing, how can it be done that when clicked on the visible div to close it and open the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: http://jsbin.com/unetay/3/edit

Comment: Update! Some improvements and it fits your needs I hope ;) http://jsbin.com/unetay/6/edit
Check my comments especially for the loop-parameter or just ask me your questions.

Comment: thanks for the update Way, but for some reason it doesn't work. I just need an extra for when clicking the visible div, to close it and show the next one. Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Clicking on the visible div closes it and shows the next one indeed. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: It doesn't do it, it doesn't close the visible div and shows the next one.

Comment: Are you sure u used the new version (with its new link)?
http://jsbin.com/unetay/6/edit

Comment: loool, now I get it... you set it that when clicked on the div and not the title. haha, I was clicking on the title and said it didn't work. Can you updated it to make it work on clicking the header with the visible div?

Comment: Sorry for that, then I missunderstood you! Here is the corrected version: http://jsbin.com/unetay/7/edit

Answer (score 2):

[See this Fiddle for a working version of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/xXXWN/8/).

```
$('.section_header h1').on('click', function(){
    $('#home > div:not(.section_header)').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('target')).show();
}).first().click();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

html:

```
<div id="home"> 

    <div class="section_header"> 
        <h1 class="left" data-target="newest">h1<?=lang('home_newest');?></h1> 
    </div> 
    <div id="newest"> 
    ... 
    </div> 

    <div class="section_header"> 
        <h1 class="left" data-target="best">h2<?=lang('home_newest');?></h1> 
    </div> 
    <div id="best"> 
        ... 
    </div> 

</div>
```

css

```
#home div { display: none;}
#home div.section_header { display:block;}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section_header > h1').click(function() {
        showOnlySingleHeader.call(this);
    });
    showOnlySingleHeader.call($('.section_header > h1[data-target="newest"]'));
});

function showOnlySingleHeader() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('target')).toggle();
    $('.section_header > h1').not(this).each(function() {
        $('#' + $(this).data('target')).hide();
    });
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrim/QBjRz/2/)

---

**EDIT** It should now comply to your requirements